# How to download file without specific content type

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I just want to download a file. But now I can only download images.

I have this:

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult DownloadFile(DownloadFileModel model, string fileName, int fileId)
        {
            //var extension = Path.GetExtension(model.FileName).TrimStart('.');
            //var extensies = Seneca.SfsLib.FileSystemHelper.UploadOptInExtensions.Contains(extension);
            string customerSchema = SfsHelpers.StateHelper.GetSchema();
            TemplateLibraryEntry entry = GetTemplateLibraryEntry(model.DesignId, customerSchema);
            FileTree tree = CreateTree(model.DesignId, entry.FilePath);           
            FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(tree.Files[fileId].FullPath);
            DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(tree.Files[fileId].FullPath);

            try {
                var fs = System.IO.File.OpenRead(fileInfo + model.FileName );
                return File(fs, "application/jpg", fileName);
            }
            catch {
                throw new HttpException(404, "Couldn't find " + model.FileName);


            }           

        }
```

But If I download a file now, I see every time downloadfile. I mean I dont see the fil name and extensie

thank you

Comment: Please format your code.

Comment: you can use `application/octet-stream` mime type for a arbitrary binary file type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using .NET 4.5 or newer then it has built in support to grab the MIME type straight from the filename.

[MSDN link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mimemapping.getmimemapping%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

You could just do:

```
return File(fs, System.Web.MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(fileName), fileName);
```